# How to remove an hover effect

Tags: css, responsive

I'm making a site responsive and i have an **hover effect on a div** but i need it to **remove it on mobile devices** using **media queries breakpoints**.

```
    .div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 4/5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 61vh;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    transition: margin-left .25s;
}

.div:hover{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 4/5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 61vh;
    display: grid;
    margin-left: -120px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    transition: margin-left .25s;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px){



/*----------Here i would like to remove the hover effect--------------*/
}
```

Comment: show your css :hover

Comment: Usually much easier if you reverse the media query, and _apply_ the effect for larger screensizes only, no? (Otherwise, you will have to overwrite/ re-set all the values you don’t like to change using another :hover rule.)

Comment: You could:

    .div {
    
    pointer-events:none
    
    }

or (not recommended) with jquery you can prevent the default
https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Instead of removing it on small sizes, I would start by applying it on larger sizes only. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Start by making the div hover effect only work on screens larger than x pixel, like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    div:hover {
        //your code
    }
}
```

The hover effect will only work on screens **larger** than 768px.

Comment: oh ok, i havent thought thaty